# ExternalProject_Add_Step ERROR add_custom_command given APPEND option with output

Tags: cmake

Using cmake version 3.7.0-rc3 on Win7, I can run the below code using ExternalProject_Add_Step no problem. But using cmake version 3.7.0 on Ubuntu16, I get the error:

```
add_custom_command given APPEND option with output "ExternalProjects/Stamp/boost/boost-CONFIGURE" which is not already a custom command output.
```

Here's simplified code that reproduces the issue.

```
ExternalProject_Add(
    boost
    URL https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.62.0/boost_1_62_0.tar.gz/download
    URL_HASH MD5=6f4571e7c5a66ccc3323da6c24be8f05
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
    BUILD_COMMAND ""
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
)

ExternalProject_Add_Step(
    boost UNIX_CONFIGURE DEPENDEES DOWNLOAD DEPENDERS CONFIGURE
    WORKING_DIRECTORY "<SOURCE_DIR>" COMMAND ./bootstrap.sh
)
```

The culprit seems to be `DEPENDERS CONFIGURE`. If I take that out, then it works fine. But... I'd like to be able to specify that the step CONFIGURE depends on this custom step, and on Windows I can, but on Ubuntu I can't. Any ideas why?

Comment: what is `UNIX_CONFIGURE` didn't see any documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see it in the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/module/ExternalProject.html), but you've just simply run into a case sensitivity issue. Modifying your `CMakeLists.txt` to:

```
❯ cat ../CMakeLists.txt 
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
include(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(
    boost
    URL https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.62.0/boost_1_62_0.tar.gz/download
    URL_HASH MD5=6f4571e7c5a66ccc3323da6c24be8f05
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
    BUILD_COMMAND ""
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
    )

ExternalProject_Add_Step(
    boost UNIX_CONFIGURE DEPENDEES download DEPENDERS configure
    WORKING_DIRECTORY "boost-prefix/src/boost/" COMMAND ./bootstrap.sh
    )
```

Notice that "download" and "configure" in `ExternalProject_Add_Step()` are now downcased. Now, cmake and make complete successfully.

```
❯ cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 8.0.0.8000042
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 8.0.0.8000042
-- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/nega/foo/build

❯ make
Scanning dependencies of target boost
[ 11%] Creating directories for 'boost'
[ 22%] Performing download step (download, verify and extract) for 'boost'
-- verifying file...
       file='/Users/nega/foo/build/boost-prefix/src/boost_1_62_0.tar.gz'
-- File already exists and hash match (skip download):
  file='/Users/nega/foo/build/boost-prefix/src/boost_1_62_0.tar.gz'
  MD5='6f4571e7c5a66ccc3323da6c24be8f05'
-- extracting...
     src='/Users/nega/foo/build/boost-prefix/src/boost_1_62_0.tar.gz'
     dst='/Users/nega/foo/build/boost-prefix/src/boost'
-- extracting... [tar xfz]
-- extracting... [analysis]
-- extracting... [rename]
-- extracting... [clean up]
-- extracting... done
[ 33%] Performing UNIX_CONFIGURE step for 'boost'
Building Boost.Build engine with toolset darwin... tools/build/src/engine/bin.macosxx86_64/b2
Detecting Python version... 2.7
Detecting Python root... /Users/nega/i3/virtenv
Unicode/ICU support for Boost.Regex?... not found.
Generating Boost.Build configuration in project-config.jam...

Bootstrapping is done. To build, run:

    ./b2

To adjust configuration, edit 'project-config.jam'.
Further information:

   - Command line help:
     ./b2 --help

   - Getting started guide: 
     http://www.boost.org/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html

   - Boost.Build documentation:
     http://www.boost.org/build/doc/html/index.html

[ 44%] No update step for 'boost'
[ 55%] No patch step for 'boost'
[ 66%] No configure step for 'boost'
[ 77%] No build step for 'boost'
[ 88%] No install step for 'boost'
[100%] Completed 'boost'
[100%] Built target boost
```

Now, look in `boost-prefix/src/boost-stamp` of your build directory:

```
❯ v boost-prefix/src/boost-stamp                       
total 32
drwxr-xr-x  15 nega  staff   510 Dec 20 12:29 ./
drwxr-xr-x   6 nega  staff   204 Dec 20 12:28 ../
-rw-r--r--   1 nega  staff     0 Dec 20 12:29 boost-UNIX_CONFIGURE
-rw-r--r--   1 nega  staff     0 Dec 20 12:29 boost-build
-rw-r--r--   1 nega  staff     0 Dec 20 12:29 boost-configure
-rw-r--r--   1 nega  staff     0 Dec 20 12:29 boost-done
-rw-r--r--   1 nega  staff     0 Dec 20 12:28 boost-download
-rw-r--r--   1 nega  staff     0 Dec 20 12:29 boost-install
-rw-r--r--   1 nega  staff     0 Dec 20 12:28 boost-mkdir
-rw-r--r--   1 nega  staff     0 Dec 20 12:29 boost-patch
-rw-r--r--   1 nega  staff     0 Dec 20 12:29 boost-update
-rw-r--r--   1 nega  staff   173 Dec 20 12:18 boost-urlinfo.txt
-rw-r--r--   1 nega  staff  4424 Dec 20 12:18 download-boost.cmake
-rw-r--r--   1 nega  staff  1611 Dec 20 12:28 extract-boost.cmake
-rw-r--r--   1 nega  staff     0 Dec 20 12:28 verify-boost.cmake
```

You'll notice at each step has a "file stamp" named after it. The default steps are all in lowercase, and your custom step "UNIX_CONFIGURE" is uppercase, just as you defined it. If you mix case your custom step, you'll get that as output.

```
❯ grep -i unix ../CMakeLists.txt 
    boost uNiX_CoNFiGuRe DEPENDEES download DEPENDERS configure
❯ make | grep -i unix
[ 33%] Performing uNiX_CoNFiGuRe step for 'boost'
❯ find boost-prefix/src/boost-stamp | grep -i unix
boost-prefix/src/boost-stamp/boost-uNiX_CoNFiGuRe
```

Also, look at the `make` output.

```
[ 22%] Performing download step (download, verify and extract) for 'boost'
[....]
[ 33%] Performing uNiX_CoNFiGuRe step for 'boost'
[....]
[ 44%] No update step for 'boost'
[ 55%] No patch step for 'boost'
[ 66%] No configure step for 'boost'
[ 77%] No build step for 'boost'
[ 88%] No install step for 'boost'
[100%] Completed 'boost'
[100%] Built target boost
```

All the default steps are referred to in lowercase.

## Summary

In CMake's `ExternalProject` module, refer to default steps in lowercase.

Comment: Addressing the actual error message, the `ExternalProject_*()` functions are wrappers around other CMake commands. `add_custom_command()` is trying to add a dependency to another custom command "boost-CONFIGURE", but it doesn't exist, because the actual name is "boost-configure".